# The Expanse: Sustained Gs during space travel

Tags: physics, the-expanse-novels

In *The Expanse* series, characters experience sustained Gs during space travel, not just during acceleration, which doesn't make sense. For instance, here's several passages from *Leviathan Wakes*, the first book in the series (tried to omit anything that could be a spoiler):

> Walking through the *Rocinante* felt surreal. [...] To walk through the spare, functional corridors, thrust gravity holding him gently to the floor...
> [p 359]

And:

> Alex had the *Rocinante* running at three-quarters of a g for 2 hours while the crew prepared and ate dinner. He would run it back up to three when the break  was over [...] Once the gravity had dropped from the crush of high acceleration, the whole crew quietly gathered in the galley...
> [p 366]

Both passages suggest that there are more Gs during acceleration, but always some amount of g-force just from moving. However real-life physics dictate that you feel g-force only  when you accelerate. If you're driving on the highway at a constant speed of 80mph, you aren't being pushed back into your seat. How is the *Rocinante* generating constant g-force, unless it is constantly accelerating? After hours and hours of travel under any amount of g-force from thrust, wouldn't the speed become unsafe? Or is there something I missed?

Comment: To the close voters: this is _**not**_ about real world science, but about the science in _The Expanse_ and how space travel works _in that universe_. This is perfectly on topic.

Comment: The answers justify the science question. Close-vote retracted.

Comment: I don't see where in the quoted text do you see them having gravity without acceleration

Comment: The first quote even explicitly states that it's thrust gravity. And the second makes it clear that they had just reduced acceleration for 2 hours so they could have dinner.

Comment: To the people that *didn't* vote to close: the question seems to make an unjustified assumption that the ship isn't thrusting when it is experiencing G forces.   I think the novels are quite clear that the ship is thrusting almost all the time and they only lower the thrust for certain periods to make movement easier and to give them a break from the high-G.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat I mean, it's literally there in the very quote the OP has posted! :D

Comment: @JasonGoemaat  & Luaan it seems obvious in hindsight but the thrust strategy used in the book isn't explained, or if it is I missed it. If someone hasn't heard of this strategy or doesn't understand "Brachistochrone trajectories", why wouldn't this be a useful question to ask?

Comment: I just boggles me.   Your question states "In The Expanse series, characters experience sustained Gs during space travel, *not just during acceleration*, which doesn't make sense".    Yet your own quotes from the books show they are under acceleration - "*thrust gravity* holding him gently to the floor".  "*Alex had the Rocinante running at* three-quarters of a g"

Comment: @JasonGoemaat again, If you're unaware of this thrust strategy, then constant thrust doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Constant thrust would cause constant acceleration.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

### The Expanse uses [torch ships](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/torchships.php) on [Brachistochrone](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/torchships.php#id--Brachistochrone_Equations) trajectories

Due to the [Epstein Drive](https://expanse.fandom.com/wiki/Epstein_Drive), fuel is not a (major) consideration so they don't need to worry about it. That means they can use the fastest/most convenient method to get from A to B; that is, accelerate until you're halfway there and then "flip and burn" and decelerate for the other half - a Brachistochrone trajectory. This is the minimum time/maximum delta-V (i.e. fuel) trajectory.

The "fastest" is by accelerating as hard as you can but that is incredibly punishing on the people. The "most convenient" is by accelerating at a comfortable rate - 1g for Earther's 1/3g for Martians, less for Belters and some compromise that upsets everyone for a mixed crew. That means that the ships experience "normal" thrust gravitation for most of their flight.

In combat or emergency circumstances, everyone straps into [crash couches](https://expanse.fandom.com/wiki/Earth_standard_gravity) and takes [dzhush](https://expanse.fandom.com/wiki/Dzhush) to push their physiology to withstand higher acceleration, [up to a point, of course](https://expanse.fandom.com/wiki/Man%C3%A9o_Jung-Espinoza_(TV)). Of course, the main engine only thrusts in the forward direction; yaw, pitch and roll are done with much less powerful thrusters that give the ship the same maneuverability irrespective of the ship's speed (because vacuum) or whether the main engine is firing (again, within limits; too much acceleration in a direction the couches aren't compensating for and splat).

Real spacecraft *do* have to worry about fuel because they use real engines not technomagic ones so they use the most *efficient* rather than the *fastest* way to get from A to B. This consists of a short burn to get you heading to your objective, a few mid-course corrections and then a capture burn if you want to get into orbit; possibly with aerobraking if your target has an atmosphere.

For going from one (near) circular orbit to another (e.g. Earth to Mars, or Low Earth Orbit to the Moon) this is the [Hohmann transfer orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer_orbit); the maximum time/minimum delta-V transfer. However, this orbit puts Mars 9 months from Earth and is only available every 26 months; the [launch window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launch_window). Compare this with a 1 g torch ship which would take 2 to 30 days depending on if Mars is on this side or the other side of the Sun (assuming you don't want to get too close to the Sun).

For interplanetary probes, you can do all sorts of cool [gravity assists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_assist) to save even more fuel because probes don't care how long it takes to get there.

Comment: I think this must have been what the authors intended, but I still find it... troubling in the practical sense, because this type of space travel would cause your speed to increase exponentially. If plotted on a graph, it would look like a hockey stick. Over long periods of time a ship could not maneuver out of the way of anything if it was off course because the speed would be too great

Comment: Up to a point - ultimately relativistic effects kick in and acceleration drops. In reality, for travel within the solar system as 1g of constant thrust, you're looking at peak velocities probably <1% speed of light, and travel times of days to months. Collision avoidance and armour is important, but not out of the question especially given the relative lack of matter once you're out of planetary orbit.

Comment: a constant acceleration does not increase your speed exponentially, but linearly. and if you burn at 1g for 1 day you reach about 850km/s - that's not insanely fast

Comment: Well, *military* ships in *The Expanse* tend to do full-acceleration/full-deceleration. Non-military ships float for the middle part of the journey, both for comfort of civilian passengers not used to high-G burns, and economic reasons (lack of juice, fuel, etc.)

Comment: Non-military ships don't do high-g burns, but from memory still go for continuous acceleration. Zero-g is as inconvenient as high-g for civilians not used to it.

Comment: "Well, military ships in The Expanse tend to do full-acceleration/full-deceleration" - no, they do not. They go with a comfortable acceleration UNLESS OTHERWISE NEEDED. As you can see in ANY military craft in the series where people walk around normally during normal operation. "Non-military ships float for the middle part of the journey, both for comfort of civilian passengers " - this makes ZERO sense. They ALSO use constant acceleration normally because especially civilian passengers ARE NOT USED TO ZERO G and need to strap in then. Unless they are collecting ice or doing something similar.

Comment: @Michael *ultimately relativistic effects kick in and acceleration drops* Yes, if you're talking about coordinate acceleration as measured by observers in some fixed inertial frame, like the Sun's rest frame. Though note there is a separate notion of [proper acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration) in relativity, which can remain constant indefinitely, and it's the proper acceleration that determines the G force felt on board the ship. See [relativistic rockets](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html) for figures on constant proper acc.

Comment: @hypnosifl Oh, absolutely. As I understood the original comment, the concern was for indefinite increase in velocity relative to the rest frame or the departure point.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - you eventually run into problems from the diffuse dust / gas causing drag (and radiation) for a ship moving at relativistic speeds wrt. to it.  The faster you're moving, the more atoms you plow into per unit time, and the more energy each collision has.  I haven't watched The Expanse yet, but it seems these aren't ramscoop ships, so at least they're not creating drag over a large area/volume swept by a magnetic field.  But for high relativistic speeds you'd want some kind of particle screening, not to mention dealing with rare micrometeoroids (e.g. via laser) in a solar system.

Comment: @inorganik "this type of space travel would cause your speed to increase exponentially." Remember that [space is big](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hv1spjsvu-A#t=7s).

Comment: @inorganik It’s not troubling; speed is the entire point.  Who wants to spend 9 *months* traveling, including carrying all the food you’d need for that, when you can (at the ideal time) get there in just two *days*?

Comment: @inorganik - "this type of space travel would cause your speed to increase exponentially" - actually it would cause the speed to increase linearly or logarithmically depending on your frame of reference.   At 1G, you would be going roughly 50% the speed of light after 15 days.  If you keep accelerating at 1G, it looks to outside observers as if your acceleration is decreasing.   1 second on your ship seems like about 1.155 seconds to an outside observer.  So to them your speed will be increasing by about 9.8 meters per 1.155 seconds, slower than 1G.

Comment: If memory serves, torch ships were ships which weren't equiped with the highly efficient (from ISP perspective) Epstein Drives.

Comment: @Aron a torch drive requires high thrust and high specific impulse - that means a lot of power which implies either a crap ton of fuel OR a highly efficient power source

Comment: @Aron Nah, torch ships were always the kind that can accelerate for the whole trip. Even in the Expanse universe, the drive system is unofficially called "the torch" all the time. They also do tea-kettle (using just steam thrusters for close manoeuvring etc.). Epstein is _a_ kind of fusion drive - there were others before it, but they had _vastly_ inferior performance. Some of these old-style drives are still used.

Comment: In-universe, the Epstein drive uses some kind of "magnetic coil exhaust acceleration" to achieve higher efficiency than a plain fusion torch drive. In reality, the exhaust acceleration system would have power requirements dwarfing what the torch itself puts out...just doubling the exhaust velocity would mean the accelerator is the source of 3/4 of the exhaust power. It would really make more sense if it was just an improved magnetic nozzle.

Comment: @TomTom I didn't mean to get you so worked up, sorry about that. They do in the books (which is what the question is tagged for), where it is not ridiculously expensive to portray zero-G. If I recall correctly, both Miller's trip to Eros and Amos' trip to Earth have extended parts in the middle "on the float." And by "full," I meant 1G burn, not balls-to-the-wall.

Comment: FWIW, an ideal [deuterium cycle](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/NucEne/fusion.html) engine converts around 260 kg of fuel to 259 kg of exhaust and 1 kg * c² energy. A ship that's 50% fuel by mass at launch running at 1 g  consumes its fuel in just under 21.9 days, reaching a speed of ~0.0618 c. Of course, a real engine will have various losses.

Comment: @PM2Ring and, of course, that much energy melts everything except unobtainium

Comment: You do not need to go 1.0g - anything from 0.7 possibly down to 0.3 would work without large problems. You can still use normal toilets, eat normally and sleep in a bed. And enjoy a nice glass of wine without too many problems. Also note that the engines in the Expanse may well break physis in terms of fuel efficiency - not sure whether this part is ever discussed outside the "brutally efficient". Expanse is hard SF with some exceptions mostly along the rings... and IIRC also fuel efficiency. Epstein to thank.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him I would count Millers trip out - was this not a belter style transport? LOW cost and belters are used to low G.

Comment: @TomTom Why are we counting belters out? More inner bigotry smdh.

Comment: Because in reality belters are used to low and zero G environments. That is not bigotry - it is not being ignorant. Facts do not care about your feelings. So, if you have someone living on an asteroid with no gravity, he may be ok with floating - more than a planet dweller.

Answer (score 15):

I understood "gravity holding him gently to the floor" to imply 'slow burn' steady acceleration, whereas "the crush of high acceleration" to me implies 'high acceleration' like when in combat and on juice, when racing to some destination in a super time-critical fashion, etc. From what I recall this is pretty consistently represented in the books (and I read the entire series, most of it twice); but if you are spoiler tolerant seen my final comment.

So these are both are cases of acceleration (often linear acceleration), and thus both cases of [artificial gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_gravity#Linear_acceleration), but low acceleration = low gravity (fractions of Earth normal), whereas high acceleration = high (i.e. crushing) gravity (multiples of Earth normal). Note that the effect of gravity on mass (in non-relativistic mechanics) is measured exactly the same way acceleration of mass is: distance divided by the square of time, as in the approximately [9.81m/s^2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravity) at Earth's surface

At the end of your question you mention the notion of 'unsafe speed': in space velocity is relative, so ideas like 'unsafe speed' that would make sense in the air, on the group, or on or under the water do not really apply.

> In later books the proto-molecule, and other technological remnants of the proto-molecule engineers exhibit control of physics beyond human ken… including inertialess motion.

Comment: I would argue there _is_ unsafe speed in space, because of 1. a higher probability of collisions because of less maneuverability, and 2. the inability to slow down in time when reaching your destination either because your speed is too great for your engine to counter before you pass you destination or you run out of fuel before you can slow down.

Comment: @inorganik colliding with what? Space is empty. If you don't put yourself on an intercept course with an object on purpose your odds of hitting anything are infinitesimally tiny. As to 2, it's obviously possible that you could accelerate yourself to a speed where you aren't able to slow down enough to "stop" (relatively) at the place you were trying to get to, but you have a big fancy astrophysics computer that calculates exactly what course you need to take to get somewhere; *why would you have ever accelerated that much in the first place?*

Comment: @Carcer because humans and computers make mistakes, and yes space is _mostly_ empty but there's a non-zero chance of collision, especially in the Expanse universe

Comment: @Inorganic  How can a spaceship see a particle of dust  - the largest thing it is likely to hit -  in its way in time to maneuvers.  Besides, the spaceship would more likely shoot a laser beame ahead of it to vaporize a dectected dust particle, and then use a magnetic field to deflect the ionized vapor, than to try to change course.  As for your second point, those spaceships flip over and start decelerating halfway to their destination, not when they get there.  Current spacecraft that don't fire their engines constantly are more likely to be unable to stop at thier destinations.

Comment: @inorganik higher probablity of collisions with things moving at high velocity **relative to you**: but **there is no velocity where *some* things are not moving at high velocity relative to you**. Wanna no get clocked hard by [Oumuamua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%BBOumuamua)? No you will get clocked hard by Luna, and vice versa.

Comment: @inorganik You've got the right sense, but it's not about avoiding collisions.  Higher velocities relative to the local star mean that you have, on average, a higher energy interaction with the local dust and solar wind, which then has implications on shielding requirements.  This is a bigger deal on very light solar sail type ships than torch ships, but it does exist.

Comment: @inorganik: A ship does not become less maneuverable when it travels faster, in the sense that it can still turn and burn just as quickly as when going slower. That being said, what does matter is that when you travel faster, you need to look further ahead (in distance) at what you might run into. But keep in mind that visibility in space is trivial. Humans can make out a planet with the naked eye from Earth. This is not accounting for radar, lack of atmosphere, and the projected time to encounter the object you're seeing. In short, it is safe to travel through space at the suggested speeds.

Comment: @inorganik: Also, fuel economy is a non-issue in The Expanse due to the highly efficient Epstein drive. This is why they so freely accelerate all the time, they have oodles of fuel reserves and it's relatively cheap to buy. In regards to slowing down, assuming you brake with the same force that you accelerated (which makes sense as it's the same G experience), the braking point is always exactly halfway. Pun intended, figuring out where to start braking is not rocket science.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, they're constantly accelerating (sometimes more, sometimes less).

Safe or not, the only way to get across the solar system in days or weeks rather than months or years is to get up to very high speeds, and the only way to get up to very high speeds while limiting acceleration to values that don't turn your crew and passengers into paste is to keep accelerating at around 1g for a very long time.

The fastest way (not the most efficient, but the fastest) to get from point A to point B is to accelerate towards B until you reach the halfway point, then flip 180 degrees and accelerate in the other direction; you will burn off all of your velocity just in time to come to rest at the destination (give or take some tweaks for gravitational effects). This is convenient if you rely on acceleration to let people walk around the ship, because you will be accelerating for 99.9% of the trip.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, in the expanse, ships that are traveling somewhere **are** constantly accelerating. The ludicrous performance of the Epstein drive allows ships the luxury of continuously accelerating/decelerating non stop throughout the flight, instead of coasting like spaceships have to do IRL. It even allows firing the engines without a destination, just to have gravity if needed, e.g. for treating injuries, since blood pools inside the body in freefall.

Comment: My reading of this is that they reduced accelleration for mealtimes, but kept going on course to their destination. They didn't just travel at 3/4 of a G for several hours for gravity.

Answer (score 5):

The only 'gravity' in space travel in The Expanse is from acceleration or deceleration.  In The Expanse more powerful ships are usually either constantly accelerating or constantly decelerating because the engines are so efficient they can do so without fuel worries so they can live with simulated gravity. When they are "on the float" they are neither accelerating nor decelerating and the crew experiences zero-g.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to cite some evidence (such as quotes from specific episodes) to support these assertions.

Comment: Pedantic note: sometimes "gravity" is from spin. (On ships, occasionally; on stations, usually.)

Comment: Also, there's the gravity from planets :P

Comment: @mattdm:  Spin gravity for ships seems rare in the *Expanse* universe.  I'm about halfway through the TV series and so far I've seen one ship (the Nauvoo/Behemoth) that has spin gravity. There may be more in the books and/or in later parts of the story, though.

Comment: An excellent and well-written answer with key information, thanks new user.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yeah, rare on ships (other examples are usually emergency situations!), but it's the standard on stations — off the top of my head from the first two books I can remember it specifically mentioned on ring stations like Tycho and Thoth, and spun-up asteroids Ceres and Eros.

Answer (score 0):

No, you understand the issues correctly. It is the universe that's lacking some concepts, thereby confusing some ideas.

You are correct, even 1g acceleration soon makes speeds rather spectacular and unsafe. For example, it would allow to go from Earth to Mars at their farthest (if they're both in aphelion and on opposite sides of the Sun) in about 10 days (50% accel, 50% decel and detour around Sun).

This distance is 401 million kilometers, maximum speed will be about 1.4% of c.

It doesn't sound much, but taking into account zodiacal dust this will mean that ship, encountering a speck of dust on the bigger end of the scale (which is 0.1 pg to 0.1 mg), will be hit with a force of anything between 15 MJ to 30 GJ (for comparison 155 HE artillery shell produces about 55 MJ, 10kT tactical nuke is about 480 GJ). Since dust density is about 5 particles per cm3, this would be near-constant bombardment of the ship's bow...

I'd say no ship would survive that, double-hull, anti-spalling and all that...

The other problem is sudden loss of gravity. Not so much for humans, but for the spaceships themselves... Space ships must have very robust structure, to deal both with positive and negative g forces, and those are very different creatures in terms of what ship herself, it's equipment and parts can be subject to. Contrary to popular belief, this is a huge problem for engineers.

And, of course, there is the question of breathable atmosphere inside of a ship... This is also tremendous force in space. We can build light on Earth, because atmospheric pressure is equalized both inside and outside your house, car, whatever. But remove atmosphere from one side of that equation and you have either boom or splat. There is an awesome video on the internet showing what happens to a railcar cistern when air is pumped out of it... *[Of course, there are vessels built to withstand that (i.e. a submarine easily deals with 1 atm of outside pressure on it's hull), but I think it's still an awesome visualisation of the atmosphere problem]*
This air pressure is number one structural concern in every vessel we currently have in space (as a humanity). Definitely ISS has that issue in spades (inflatable compartments notwithstanding, no matter how cool they are - and they are very cool!!). And, of course, atmosphere has a mass too - which is 1.3 kg/m3, so if ship is big enough it needs to be accounted for.

Yet another problem is mass distribution. It is not a great example, but in a space shuttle astronauts and their equipment/cargo are carefully laid out, not just piled on top of one another... And there's a reason EVERYTHING there is strapped down - astronauts including (and they're not moving during boost for that reason as well; though it's hard to do anything at 3g). Sudden, even small change in distribution of mass inside ship during accel/decel and results can be catastrophic. Now, space shuttle is not the *Donnager*, but those rules still apply...

So, bottom-lining it all, I agree with you that there's a lot missing in there to complete the picture...

Comment: The dust issue makes sense, but I'm not following you about the atmosphere. I mean... https://spacenews.com/beam-module-fully-expanded-on-space-station/

Comment: @mattdm But what g-force ISS is experiencing? But I get your meaning, will edit for better clarification.

Comment: Your rail car example is disingenuous.  A spaceship acts as a balloon not a vacuum vessel, and there are no issues with things like the ISS enduring a single atmosphere's worth of pressure.  The equivalent to your rail car is a submarine - which we can easily build to withstand 30 atmospheres of external pressure.

Comment: @PeterM I believe I used this as an example of what happens when atmo is removed from one side of equation, not focusing on interior. ANd yes, it will act as a balloon, but it still needs reinforcing. Elastic skin helps keep everything inside (like human in vacuum), but hard shell means something different... And sub is resilient, but what happens when torpedo explodes nearby?

Comment: @AcePL When atmosphere is released on a space ship the forces on the skin reduce to zero - the opposite of your rail car example.  And because of the internal structure of a space ship, a torpedo exploding nearby is not going to cause the same effect as popping a balloon, it will simply vent the atmosphere.  And any ship designer building warships in space is going to construct them around multiple air-tight compartments in order to minimize such venting in the same way that modern day warships have multiple watertight compartments to help prevent sinking when the hull is breached.

Comment: @PeterM "*@AcePL When atmosphere is released on a space ship the forces on the skin reduce to zero*" That statement violates several laws of physics. Of course, space ship can be constructed so that atmo pressure can be counteracted, but what you said is wrong. But as I wrote earlier, I shall edit that section so that what I meant will be clearer.

Comment: @AcePL If there is zero atmosphere on both sides of the skin, then how is the net force **not** zero?

Comment: @PeterM You mean when ship is depressurized? Then yeah, you're right. But what of it?